# Send objects over WebSocket without using stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

Is it possible to send a simple JavaScript object over Web-Socket without using `stringify`?

Example of object:

```
( `{type: 'text', data: 'foo'}` )
```

I managed to send an object without using `stringify` from the client side but, on the server side, I can't access its methods or properties.

Comment: Did you parse the JSON on the server side?

Comment: why would I need to parse, as I didn't send it using JSON.stringify? @Carcigenicate

Comment: I'm saying when you did stringify it. And how did you send it without using `stringify`?

Comment: yes, when I send using stringify it does work. I'm asking, is it possible to send without stringify?

Comment: no, you can only send text and bins, not structures